# Trying to run PL/SQL script using Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I'm familiar with Java JDBC and use it often to run simple SQLs. However, I want to run something like the below. This is more PL/SQL than regular SQL, hence my problems. I am not running this from the Oracle box but from my own computer. Can someone help me to run this kind of PL/SQL using Java?

```
spool C:\count.txt;
DEFINE date="TO_DATE ('08-29-2011','mm-dd-yyyy')";
SET NEWPAGE 0;
SET SPACE 0;
SET LINESIZE 500;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SET ECHO OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET VERIFY OFF;
SET HEADING OFF;
SET TRIMSPOOL ON;
alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi';
select 'TABLE1', count(*) from SCHEMA.TABLE1 where modifyts < &date;
select 'TABLE2', count(*) from SCHEMA.TABLE2 where modifyts < &date;
select 'TABLE3', count(*) from SCHEMA.TABLE3 where modifyts < &date;
spool off;
```

Comment: Hmm, are you asking how to run pl\sql from your Java Client. I am sorry I am having trouble understanding your question and especially your solution. If you are just trying to run PL\SQL, then you should create a function or procedure in your oracle database and use java to just call the routine.

Comment: Did you already try plain [Statement.execute(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String))? For the SELECTs you'll probably have to use the `getResultSet()`, `getUpdateCount()`, `getMoreResults()` mentioned in that methods `@SeeAlso`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SPOOL`, `DEFINE`, and `SET` are all SQL*Plus commands.  They are not valid in PL/SQL or in SQL.  You cannot, therefore, run this sort of script through a tool other than SQL*Plus (or a tool that supports SQL*Plus commands like SQL Developer or Toad).

You could, of course, have your Java application call out to the operating system to invoke the SQL*Plus executable (assuming it is installed on the machine that the Java application is running on) and pass the script to SQL*Plus.  But that's generally way more complexity than you need.  It would make more sense to either just use SQL*Plus or to issue just the `SELECT` statements from your Java application and use Java's file I/O classes to write the results to a file.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I should be doing. I didn't remember that most of those commands are SQL*Plus only.